# How do I make a DataGridView immediately commit edits?

Tags: c#, datagridview, master-detail, undo

I have a master-detail layout with a section of popup menus (the Details) and a section with a DataGridView which holds the rows.

The popup-menu state is updated when the selected row in the DataGridView changes and the state in the DGV's selected row should update when the popup-menu changes.

All of this works *except* the row in the DataGridView doesn't immediately update when I change the value of the popup-menu. I have to select a different row in order to see my edits.

I'm assuming this is because the edit hasn't been committed until the selection changes.

My question is: How do I make the change to the popup become immediately reflected in the DataGridView?

I have experimented with calling EndEdit() in the SelectionChangeCommitted handler for the popup-menu, but this has no effect. I'm interested in a technique that would allow me to create a DataGridView that would behave as if there were no Undo mechanism to begin with. Ideally the solution would be generic and transplantable to other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what was going on. The answer was in the properties of the `ComboBox` instances. I needed to change their `DataSourceUpdateMode` from `OnValidation` to `OnPropertyChanged`. This makes sense. The `DataGridView` was very likely showing the current state of the data. It was just that the data hadn't been edited yet because focus had not left the `ComboBox`, validating the input.

Thanks to everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like existing answers work well with [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx)s. In my case, where a [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) was directly used as the [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx), they didn't work for some reason.

```csharp
// Other answers didn't work in my setup...
private DataGridView dgv;

private Form1()
{
   var table = new DataTable();
   // ... fill the table ...
   dgv.DataSource = table;
}
```

After some hair-pulling, I got it work without adding `BindingSource` indirection:

```csharp
// Add this event handler to the DataGridView
private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dgv.BindingContext[dgv.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
}

private Form1()
{
   // Add the event handler above
   dgv.CellEndEdit += dgv_CellEndEdit;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. We each cell to be applied without having to click on another row.

Answer (score 4):

this works well for me:

```
private void CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dgw = (DataGridView) sender;
    dgw.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this extension method. It works for all columns types, not just ComboBoxes:

```
        public static void ChangeEditModeToOnPropertyChanged(this DataGridView gv)
        {
            gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                gv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                if (gv.CurrentCell == null)
                    return;
                if (gv.CurrentCell.EditType != typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
                    return;
                gv.BeginEdit(false);
                var textBox = (TextBox)gv.EditingControl;
                textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
            };
        }
```

This method commits every change just after the change is made.

When we have a text column, after typing a character, its value will commit to the DataSource and the editmode of the cell will end.

Therefore current cell should return to edit mode, and position of the cursor set to end of text in order to enable user to continue typing reminder of the text.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me. little changing:

```
if (sender is DataGridView { IsCurrentCellDirty: true, EditingControl: TextBox txb } dgv)
{
    var start = txb.SelectionStart;

    dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    (dgv.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem as DataRowView)?.EndEdit(); //for computed column

    txb.Select(start, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the [DataGridView.EndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit.aspx) method.

Comment: Should have added more detail. I know EndEdit will cause that to happen. What do I need to observe in order to know *when* to call it?

Comment: @MichaelBishop it may be that you need the current message dispatch to fully complete before calling EndEdit. Use `BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>dgv.EndEdit())`. This works because BeginInvoke uses PostMessage to post a WM_USER message that the WinForms message pump uses to implement BeginInvoke.

Comment: Thanks. `BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>dgv.EndEd‌​it()))` was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: doesnt work even with BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.EndEdit()));

Answer (score -1):

following will work

```
_dataGrid.EndEdit()
```

s fine once you set the value.

Comment: Not true, will not work