# Best place to implement DataGridView extension method for changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I hope this isn't a trivial question as I'm still pretty new to VS C# and WINFORMS.

T.Rahgooy answered a question on link [How do I make a DataGridView immediately commit edits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462667/how-do-i-make-a-datagridview-immediately-commit-edits/17964384#17964384)  It didn't get any votes but looked like something I'd like to try and so far it appears to work beautifully.

Being pretty new to VS C# & Winforms I was unsure where to install it and where to call it.  I placed it at the top of my namespace (had to create a class to contain it first) and then called it from RowDirtyStateNeeded event (which I added)

Questions:
1) Is there a better place to install the extension method, i.e. an existing class ?
2) Is there a better place to call the method?

```
namespace VX130
{
    public static class ExtensionHelpers
    {
        public static void ChangeEditModeToOnPropertyChanged(this DataGridView gv)
        {
            //Use this extension method. It works for all columns types, not just ComboBoxes:
            // This method commits every change just after the change is made.  When we have a text column, after typing a character, 
            //its value will commit to the DataSource and the editmode of the cell will end.  Therefore current cell should return to 
            //ed
            gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                gv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                if (gv.CurrentCell == null)
                    return;
                if (gv.CurrentCell.EditType != typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
                    return;
                gv.BeginEdit(false);
                var textBox = (TextBox)gv.EditingControl;
                textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a class so it should be in its own code file.  I'd suggest that it would be a good idea to create a library of extension methods that you can then reference in any future project(s).  You might want to break your methods up into multiple libraries or use just one.

Comment: What happen if user want change cell value in the middle of current value? From code i assume, user will need to put cursor back in the middle after every character he input