# Syntax of the attached extension method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm a C# beginner and downloaded the extension method in [How do I make a DataGridView immediately commit edits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462667/how-do-i-make-a-datagridview-immediately-commit-edits) The method works great but don't understand the syntax.

My question is to ask an explanation of the syntax on two lines.
  1st line: `gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, args) =>`  what is `+=` and `=>` for???
  2nd line: `};`   Why is semicolon needed here?

```
    public static void ChangeEditModeToOnPropertyChanged(this DataGridView gv)
    {
        gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            gv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            if (gv.CurrentCell == null)
                return;
            if (gv.CurrentCell.EditType != typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
                return;
            gv.BeginEdit(false);
            var textBox = (TextBox)gv.EditingControl;
            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
        };
    }
```

Comment: You're dealing with events (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) and lambdas (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see there is a Lambda Expression. A Lambda Expression is a very concise syntax for an inline definition of a method, a so called anonymous delegate.

Instead of declaring ...

```
private void Cell_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    some code;
}
```

... and the event declaration ...

```
gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += Cell_StateChanged;
```

... you write

```
gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, args) => { some code; };
```

The part before the `=>` (pronounced "goes to")  is the argument list. The types need not be declared, because they are inferred from the declaration of the event `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`.

The part to right of `=>` is the method body.

The semicolon at the end is just the same semicolon as in `gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += Cell_StateChanged;`.

You can even drop the braces, if there is only one statement:

```
gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, args) => Print(args);
```

---

Lambda Expressions can also be used for function methods:

```
Func<double, double> f = x => x * x; // You can drop the () if there is only 1 argument
```

Here `x => x * x` performs the same calculation as

```
private double Square(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

The assignments `Func<double, double> f = x => x * x;` and `Func<double, double> f = Square;` are equivalent. So

```
double y = f(3);
// y = 9
```

---

I have not explained the `+=` yet. This operator is used to attach an event handler to an event. In VB you would write more explicitly

```vb
AddHandler gv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf Cell_StateChanged
```

Answer (score 0):

For an overall explanation, all that method does is assign an event on the `DataGridView` to an anonymous function (lambda expression).

Now for the syntax:

- `+=` is adding the operand on the right to the event on the left. Events are multicast delegates, so one event invocation can trigger multiple functions (hence the "+=" instead of "=", you are adding to the list).
- `=>` is part of the lambda syntax. Typically, a lambda looks like `(<args>) => { expressions }`. There are shorthand versions, but your example follows this syntax. In english, we say "such that" when this symbol is encountered.
- There is a `;` after the closing `}` for the lambda expression because you are completing a statement, namely, that of the assignment to the event.

Comment: Thank you.  Wish I could mark both as answer because your explanation is clear and concise and was easier to understand than the accepted answer.

Comment: @ThomAsh The other answer was certainly more complete :) No worries though, glad I could help.