# DataGridView doesn't change DataSource's value Immediately

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Class with a DataTable. 
DataTable have 2 columns, 'checkbox' and 'value'

In other Form class, I located instance of Class.
and also DataGridView which DataSource is Class's DataTable

Problem is that when i try to get DataTable's Value using method inside class by occurring the event of DataGridView, it's not updated. when event occurs DataTable value remain in previous state of event occurs.

Here is my code...

```
public class DataClass
{
    public DataTable Dt { get; set; }

    public DataClass()
    {
        Dt = new DataTable();
        Dt.Columns.Add("CheckBox", typeof(bool));
        Dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        Dt.Rows.Add(false, 123);
        Dt.Rows.Add(false, 456);
    }

    public void AnalizeDataTableValue()
    {
        var numberValues = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow row in Dt.Rows)
        {
            // Checked?
            bool doThat = bool.Parse(row["CheckBox"].ToString());
            if (doThat == false)
                continue;

            numberValues.Add(int.Parse(row["Value"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
    private DataClass _DtClass;

    public MyForm()
    {
        _DtClass = new DataClass();

        Datagridview1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn() {DataPropertyName = "CheckBox" });
        Datagridview1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { DataPropertyName = "Value" });
        Datagridview1.DataSource = _DtClass.Dt;
    }

    private void Datagridview1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        _DtClass.AnalizeDataTableValue();
    }
}
```

In this code, if i change value of DataGridView and leave control, event occurs and method 'AnalizeDataTableValue()' run.
And I must get Changed DataTable value but it's not.
If I change dataGridView's value once again. I can get previously changed state..

I think DataGridView doesn't change DataSource after occuring event.

Comment: this Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462667/how-do-i-make-a-datagridview-immediately-commit-edits solved my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a DataGridView immediately commit edits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462667/how-do-i-make-a-datagridview-immediately-commit-edits)