# Why is the EditedFormattedValue and the acutal displayed value not updating in this DataGridView ComboBox cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a column of comboboxes. These comboboxes can hold a number between 1-24. I have 8 rows in the the DGV and I want to prevent any two rows from having the same number selected in the combobox. If the CB that changed conflicts with any other CB I set the one that changed back to the previous value stored in "CorrectSlotSelections". If the change is valid and has no conflicts I update the value stored in "CorrectSlotSelections".

This all works properly, however the value displayed on screen does not update if it was found to be invalid, even though I overwrite the incorrect value. Upon inspection of the DGV in debug mode I can see that I have poperly overwritten the value, but the property "EditedFormattedValue" does still show the old, incorrect, value.  How can I change this to update the UI so it shows the corrected value?

```
// This event handler manually raises the CellValueChanged event 
// by calling the CommitEdit method. 
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ChannelConfigDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        // This fires the cell value changed handler below
        ChannelConfigDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void ChannelConfigDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)ChannelConfigDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
    if (cb.Value != null)
    {
        // Check all rows for a cell in column 3 that has the value that was just changed.
        List<DataGridViewRow> rowsWithDuplicateValue = ChannelConfigDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => (int)x.Cells[2].Value == (int)cb.Value).ToList();
        if (rowsWithDuplicateValue == null || rowsWithDuplicateValue.Count() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If more than one item with this value was found we must handle the duplicates.
        if (rowsWithDuplicateValue.Count() > 1)
        {
            ChannelConfigDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = CorrectSlotSelections[e.RowIndex];
        }
        // If only one was found update the correct slot selections.
        else if(rowsWithDuplicateValue.Count() == 1)
        {
            CorrectSlotSelections[e.RowIndex] = (int)cb.Value;
        }
        ChannelConfigDataGridView.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.editedformattedvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462667/how-do-i-make-a-datagridview-immediately-commit-edits

Comment: The SO link was the solution to my problem. I needed to call EndEdit() after CommitEdit().