# DataGridView commit changes to data source on cell exit, rather than only on Enter keypress

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I have a situation analogous to the following snippet:

```
        static BindingSource dataTableBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        static DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col. 1", typeof(string)));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col. 2", typeof(string)));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col. 3", typeof(string)));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col. 4 (int)", typeof(int)));

            dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            dataTable.AcceptChanges();

            dataTableBindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
            dataGridView.DataSource = dataTableBindingSource;

            dataTable.RowChanged += DataTableRowChanged;
        }

        private static void DataTableRowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            dataTable.RowChanged -= DataTableRowChanged;

            // Calculations are performed (e.g. autofilling table values)

            dataTable.AcceptChanges();
            dataTable.RowChanged +=DataTableRowChanged;
        }
```

My code works correctly when the user presses Enter after editing a cell, however I need the `dataTable.RowChanged` event to occur at any time after the user leaves a cell.

I have tried adding an event handler to `dataGridView.CellValueChanged`, which is called at all the times I require. However, if the user has added a new row and the `dataTable.RowChanged` event has not yet occurred (e.g. The user has pressed Tab rather than Enter), the new row will not yet be present in the `DataTable`. It seems that when new rows are created by the user in the `DataGridView` Control that the entire row is held in some internal "temporary" variable until the user presses enter or tabs through to a new row.
Ideally I would be able to tell the `DataGridView` to apply the "temporary" new row to the DataTable from within the `dataGridView.CellValueChanged` event, but I cannot find a way to achieve this. I have tried calling each of the following from within the `dataGridView.CellValueChanged` event with no success:

```
faultDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
faultDataGridView.Update();
faultDataGridView.EndEdit();
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465701/10910795) mentions the property `DataSourceUpdateMode`, which appears to be similar to what I require. Unfortunately I cannot find any source explaining how I would set this value, or anything analogous to it for the Controls I'm using

I would prefer to keep all of my autofill logic in one location, referring only to values in the `DataTable`, however if I cannot send new rows to the `DataTable` immediately after the user leaves a cell I do not see how this is possible.

Comment: You have an infinite loop in the `DataTableRowChanged` event. The last line… `dataTable.AcceptChanges();`… is going to re-fire the event. I am confident accept changes needs to be called “before” the event is re-subscribed.

Comment: @JohnG You're correct, thank you. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: In my tests, if the user types any character into a cell in the “new” row of the grid, THEN a “new” row is added to the underlying data table. However, as you note this does not fire your current event. I am guessing you may be looking for the grids `CellEndEdit` event. This event fires when the user leaves a cell after editing it. My question would be “what” calculation would you want to make “before” the user has entered any data on that row? In other words, if a new row is added “what” do you want to do? If default values are needed, then the grid has a `DefaultValuesNeeded` event.

Comment: I have tested using dataGridView.CellEndEdit, however the new row is not present in the DataTable at when viewed from within this event.

What I want to do is to be able to fill in values of the table as soon as the user has entered enough values for the remainder to be calculated. Ideally this means that the autofill method would be called on every cell value change, including those that add new rows as part of the event. The autofill method can then work out if there are any values that can be calculated and update the table accordingly.

Comment: I am mistaken and you are correct, the table row is not added if the user presses the tab key. I am struggling to understand what exactly you mean by… _”What I want to do is to be able to fill in values of the table as soon as the user has entered enough values for the remainder to be calculated.”_ … ? … What would be considered “enough values”? And what would be calculated if there were enough “required” values?

Comment: In addition if these “other” cell values are “calculated” from existing cells, then it sounds like using an “Expression” column for those columns may be a better solution. It would help to know “what” is getting calculated and “when.” What values are needed to make these calculations? Your current approach is just checking if ANY cell is changed, I would think you would need to check if the other “required” values are present before “calculating” the other cell values. Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I believe you are understanding correctly.

Examples of calculated values are `start index`, `length`, and `end index`. If any two of those values are known, the other can be calculated. Likewise, if any one value is changed, then another value must also change. I understand that having three cells is over-specifying, but user has requested that all three are available.

As far as I am aware an expression based column would not work, since any of the three columns must be able to be provided or calculated.

Comment: Read the notes here: [Bound DataGridView not updating to display information + sorting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006605/7444103) -- It's not clear (to me) what you're trying to do, based on the code you're showing. Are you trying to add calculated values to Cells of the same Row the User is editing? Then, what? Store these values to the underlying DataTable right after? It that's the case, what has  `dataTable.AcceptChanges();` (or `dataTable.RowChanged`) to do with this? Do you know what that method does? Just follow the description  I linked and update the question, if necessary.

Comment: See also: [Correct event to calculate Cells values in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62291110/7444103)